# display result from a query

Tags: php, kohana

I'm learning kohana 3.3. I'm working on the model part. Basic query. But i don't know how to display the results i got from a query.

Here's the model.

**APPPATH/classes/model/people.php**

```
class Model_People extends Model {

    public function show_data() {
        $query = DB::query(Database::SELECT, 'SELECT * FROM people');
        return $query;
    }

}
```

**APPPATH/classes/controller/people.php**

```
class Controller_People extends Controller {

    public function action_index() {
        $model = Model::factory('people');
        $view = View::factory('base_template');
        $model->user = $model->show_data();
        $this->response->body($view);
    }

}
```

**APPPATH/views/base_template.php**

```
<?php 
    foreach($user as $row) {
        echo "<h2>".$row['Name']."</h2>";
    } 
?>
```

I don't want to use ORM I'm using QUERY BUILDER. When I run the code it says variable user not defined. How do I display the results correctly? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
class Controller_People extends Controller {

    public function action_index() {
        $model = Model::factory('people');

        $view = View::factory('base_template');
        $view->user = $model->show_data();

        $this->response->body($view);
    }
}
```

then loop in view

```
<?php 
    foreach($user as $row) :
        echo "<h2>".$row['Name']."</h2>";
    endforeach; 
?>
```

Comment: No more error but nothing is displayed?. Do i still need the execute()?

Comment: yes just add ``->execute()`` at the end of your query ``DB::query(Database::SELECT, 'SELECT * FROM people')->execute();``

Answer (score 2):

Since you are learning Kohana, I would suggest using [ORM](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/orm), Kohana offers quite a powerful module for this.

After enabling the module you can use it like this

**Model_People**

```
class Model_People extends ORM {

}
```

**Controller_People**

```
public function action_index() {
    $people = ORM::factory('People')->find_all();
    $view = View::factory('base_template');
    $view->people = $people;

    $this->response->body($view);
}
```

**base_template**

```
<?php foreach ($people as $person) : ?>
    <h2><?php echo $person->Name; ?></h2>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

ORM offers many advantages, such as [relationships](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/orm/relationships), [validation](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/orm/validation) and [filters](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/orm/filters). Without you having to write complex additional code (such as DB expressions).

---

Additionally when working on views, you might want to use a Controller that extends [`Controller_Template`](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Controller_Template) instead of `Controller`

Comment: You are welcome. Kohana has powerful classes built in - the sooner you learn on how to use them, the more you profit and can concentrate on parts of your code that really matter ;)