# How to load model in controller in kohana3.3.1?

Tags: kohana

How to load model in kohana and how to call the methods of this model to retrieve some data from database and show the data in views.
Just like in codeigniter, I want to load the model in controller,call its method say getAll(), and then pass this data to view.

Can anybody help me in this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you researched this at all? I suggest reading the [documentation](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/) and you'll figure this out in no time.

Comment: I have been searching for the last 3 hours but found nothing useful.

Comment: Have you looked at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20351528/display-result-from-a-query) e.g.? You need to be more specific and paste your most promising attempts before we can really help you (this is too broad atm)

Answer (score 0):

Kohana uses "Autoloading". If it doesn't find a class, it will search for it. You can read about it here http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/autoloading .

You just need to write in your controller

```
public action_index()
{
    $model = new Model_Foo;

    $items = $model->get_all();
    ...
}
```

This depends on you to have a get_all() function in your model. You can use ORM models or create your own. Read in the docs about it here http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/mvc/models .